# Count objects in queryset by value in a field. Django

Tags: django, django-orm

Imagine I have a model which looks something like following:

```
class Car(models.Model):

    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (1: 'Hatchback')
        (2: 'Saloon')

    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, ...)

    color = models.CharField()

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
```

And I want to count objects by specific values. Say black saloons owned by Johns or white hatchbacks owned by Matts.

The best what I came up so far is:

```
Car.objects.annotate(
    black_saloons_owned_by_Johns=Count(
        'type',
        filter=(
            Q(type=2) &
            Q(owner__first_name='John')
        )
    ),
    white_hatchbacks_owned_by_Matts=Count(
        'type',
        filter=(
            Q(type=1) &
            Q(owner__first_name='Matt')
        )
    )
).aggregate(
    aggregated_black_saloons_owned_by_Johns=Sum(
        'black_saloons_owned_by_Johns'
    ),
    aggregated_white_hatchbacks_owned_by_Matts=Sum(
        'white_hatchbacks_owned_by_Matts'
    )
)
```

Is there a better way to get the desired result? Thanks.

**Update.**

As I said, I need to perform multiple lookups in a single query. The query I used had just one example. I updated it. Should have explicitly point it out. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can filter the queryset, and then use [**`.count()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
Car.objects.filter(type=2, owner__first_name='John').count()
```

or if you need to perform multiple lookups, you can use `.aggregate(..)` directly:

You can `Count` the `Car` objects directly with:

```
Car.objects.aggregate(
    total_john=Count(
        'pk', filter=Q(type=2, owner__first_name='John')
    ),
    total_matts=Count(
        'pk', filter=Q(type=1, owner__first_name='Matt')
    )
)
```

this will then return a dictionary that has two keys: `'total_john'` and `'total_matts'`, and these will contain the count of their number of `Car`s respectively.

Comment: Note that Q lookup is mostly used for "or" lookups. The comma in this answer stands for "and" - type=2 AND owner__first_name='John'

Comment: @joshlsullivan: well the filter in the question uses `&` which means that it is the conjunction of two conditions, not the disjunction.

Comment: @joshlsullivan: it would also conflict with the question text, since we want to count the number of saloons owned by a person named John, not the number of cars of type 2 or owned by John.

Comment: That's what I meant.